# Which is better: "discussion" or "dialogue"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dialogue), the word "dialogue" in the sense 'discussion' is used especially for discussion between **opposing** groups. So, now I'm wondering whether it is better to call a formal discussion between groups that are not in any way opposing "discussion", or if it is still possible to use the word "dialogue"?

Example

> The December dialogue/discussion is when all the departments meet to discuss and evaluate customer service.

Comment: I think the only facts that can be shared on this have already been found in your research (well done for researching it, by the way). 'Dialogue' *does* have the use and therefore that connotation. Any further comment on whether you should or should not use it is likely to be opinion-based. On that basis, I'd say you should use 'discussion' in your context.

Comment: I don't think either word is a good fit in this context; you're talking about an event, not just an exchange of words. Maybe "meeting"?

Comment: Other options would be meeting, "conference" or "powwow". "Dialogue" shouldn't be considered just a discussion between opposing views, but either way, it's a little awkward here, and "discussion" is awkward in that "discuss" is used in the same sentence.

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughts! Much appreciated! I really like "conference" for this – that's pretty much exactly what it is :)

Comment: Dialogue means a discussion between two parties.  If there are more than two, it cannot be a dialogue.

Comment: @Chenmunka Oh? I didn't know that! Is this generally adhered to though? I mean, is that the way it's actually used?

Comment: It depends on how formal these interdepartmental discussions are. If it is a formal meeting with someone in charge and taking minutes then call it a **meeting**, if, on the other hand, it's a meeting after work down the pub, then possibly **get together** or **chat** might work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "discussion" if the purpose of the meeting is to discuss something.

I can understand not wanting to use both "discussion" and discuss" in the same sentence.  But there are lots of words you could use.  "Dialogue" is one, or "meeting", "gathering", etc

Comment: Thanks! So you'd say "dialogue" would work after all? Even without there being any opposition between the ones meeting? Either way, I think I'll go with "conference", as suggested by @ralph.m, since that's pretty much exactly what I'm after :)